# Angular Ionic App - ui-slider won't show up and neither ion-range-how can I make it visible?

Tags: angularjs, slider

I am trying to include a ui-slider in my ionic app but it just won't show up. I also tried to use ionic-range but it won't show up as well.. I installed ui-slider, required it and loaded it in my index.html file.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="generate()" ng-show="!gen">  
Generate Random Password</button>
    <div ng-show="gen">
        <h3>Length</h3><slider floor="8" ceiling="20" step="1" precision="1"   
         ng-model="leng" translate="currencyFormatting"></slider>
        <h3>Symbols</h3><slider floor="0" ceiling="{{leng - nums}}" step="1"   
   precision="1" ng-model="syms" translate="currencyFormatting"></slider>
        <h3>Numbers</h3><slider floor="0" ceiling="{{leng - syms}}" step="1"     
 precision="1" ng-model="nums" translate="currencyFormatting"></slider>
    <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="generatePassword(leng, syms, nums)"> Generate! </button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example for Ionic slider.

http://codepen.io/zhipeng/pen/gBdDE

You might wanna use something like:

`<div class="range" id="green">
        <input type="range" name="syms" ng-model="syms" min="0" max="12">
 </div>`